# How to create mutually dependent widgets using PyQt?

Tags: design-patterns, pyqt, widget

I'm trying to implement 2 PyQt widgets that both influence a color value. If one is changed by the user, then the other should be adapted and vice versa.
The implementation I have pursued thus far uses a method that receives signals from either widget and changes the data of the widgets accordingly.

Not being a software engineer myself, I have the impression that this strategy results in some sort of loop, resulting in undesired behavior. Perhaps some design pattern exists to deal with such a situation?

I do realize that this question may be somewhat ill-posed, so I am hoping for feedback to improve.

Here is the part of the code that seems relevant to the question:

```
class Gui(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)

        self.seed_color_line_edit = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Enter a hex color code...')
        self.hue_slider = QLabeledSlider(Qt.Horizontal)

    ...

        self.seed_color_line_edit.editingFinished.connect(self.set_color)
        self.hue_slider.valueChanged.connect(self.set_color)

    ...

    @pyqtSlot()
    def set_color(self):

    my_sender = self.sender()

    if type(my_sender) is QLabeledSlider:
            c = (self.hue_slider.value() / 360, 1, 1)
            hex_color = rgb2hex(c)  # (hue, sat, val))
            self.seed_color_line_edit.setText(hex_color)

        if type(my_sender) is QLineEdit:
            hex_color = self.seed_color_line_edit.text()
            hsv = rgb_to_hsv(hex2rgb(hex_color))
            hue, sat, val = int(hsv[0] * 360), int(hsv[1] * 100), int(hsv[2] * 100)
            self.hue_slider.setValue(hue)
```

The above code does not produce the desired behavior. If the hue QLabeledSlider is moved, then the hex color code in the QLineEdit widget is changed correctly. However, if the hex color QLineEdit is changed, then this change is either ignored, or the QLineEdit data is changed to a different value.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for the suggestion. By creating this minimal example, I believe I managed to find the reason for the unintended behavior, and devised a work-around. I will post that as an answer. Still, I suspect this is not a proper way to deal with the issue,

Answer (score 0):

Since a color value is represented in a 3D space, e.g. HSV, 3 inputs are needed to define a color. When using a hex color code RGB representation, a change of this hex code by a user should update the h, s, and v values. In a straightforward PyQt solution, the HSV values are contained in 3 QSlider objects, and the hex color value in a QLineEdit object. Now, using signals between the various objects, a situation can arise in which a hex code change first triggers an h value update, and subsequently an s and v value update. However, when the h value is updated first, then this causes a signal back to the hex color QLineEdit object, but with the previous s and v values. As a result, the hex color value is updated as well, but to a different value than the user had entered.

A minimal example showing this behavior is given below. Here, the values of 2 QSlider objects determine the value in a QLineEdit object, via some formula (intended to simulate hex to hsv or hsv to hex conversion). If the QLineEdit value is changed, then two signals to the QSlider objects are generated successively, which in turn generate signals to the QLineEdit object.

Now the workaround I found simply blocks any outgoing signals when the set of slider values is being updated.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QSlider
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot


class Gui(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Gui, self).__init__(parent)

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.slider1 = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider2 = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)

        self.line_edit.editingFinished.connect(self.setter)
        self.slider1.valueChanged.connect(self.setter)
        self.slider2.valueChanged.connect(self.setter)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider1)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def setter(self):
        my_sender = self.sender()

        if type(my_sender) is QSlider:
            a = self.slider1.value()
            b = self.slider2.value()
            print(f'setter QSlider {a} {b}')
            self.line_edit.setText(str(a+b))

        if type(my_sender) is QLineEdit:
            self.slider1.blockSignals(True)
            self.slider2.blockSignals(True)
            c = int(self.line_edit.text())
            a = c // 2
            b = c - a
            print(f'setter QLineEdit {a} {b} {c}')
            self.slider1.setValue(a)
            self.slider2.setValue(b)
            self.slider1.blockSignals(False)
            self.slider2.blockSignals(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Gui()
    mw.show()
    app.exec_()
```